# How to prove $a_{2n}=\max\limits_{0<d<2n}a_d\cdot a_{2n-d}=a_n^2$ for $n\geq 2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$a_1=0$, $a_2=2$, $a_3=3$, $a_n=\max\limits_{0<d<n}a_d\cdot a_{n-d}$ for $n\geq 4$. I want to prove that $a_{2n}=\max\limits_{0<d<2n}a_d\cdot a_{2n-d}=a_n^2$ for $n\geq 2$. Can I do that by induction?

Answer (score 3):

Using your initial set of values and your formula, I got the following set of values:

$$a_1=0, a_2=2, a_3=3, a_4 = 4, a_5 = 6, a_6 = 9, a_7 = 12, a_8 = 18 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Specifically, using your $a_n=\max\limits_{0<d<n}a_d\cdot a_{n-d}$ formula, I got $a_4 = a_2(a_2) = 4$. Next, $a_5 = a_2(a_3) = 6$. Also, I found that $a_6 = a_3(a_3) = 9$. In addition, I determined that $a_7 = a_2(a_5) = a_3(a_4) = 12$.

Finally, I calculated $a_8 = a_2(a_6) = a_3(a_5) = 18$, but $a_4^2 = 4^2 = 16$. Thus, your hypothesis fails for $n = 4$. Is there possibly a mistake with your initial values, the equation you provided or something else?

Comment: Similarly, $a_{14}≥a_6\times a_8=9\times 12=162>a_7^2=144$.

Comment: Well, I thought it was correct - seems like it isn't. I have to find $a_{19702020}$...