# Finding the a particular element of a recursive sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given $a_1=0$, $a_2=2$, $a_3=3$, $a_n=\max\limits_{0<d<n}a_d\cdot a_{n-d}$ ($n\geq 4$), what is $a_{19702020}$?

It's the sequel to this question: [How to prove $a_{2n}=\max\limits_{0<d<2n}a_d\cdot a_{2n-d}=a_n^2$ for $n\geq 2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3564849/how-to-prove-a-2n-max-limits-0d2na-d-cdot-a-2n-d-a-n2-for-n-geq-2)

I thought I found a forumla, but I was wrong

Comment: I should add that I am looking for the prime factorization of $a_{19702020}$

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: That should be $5\le n\le 100$ ($a_4=4\ne 3a_1=0$).

Comment: $a_n = 3a_{n-3}$ is correct for $5\leq n \leq 10000$.

Comment: How does this help with finding the prime factorization of $a_{19702020}$?

Answer (score 2):

Using Christian Blatter's observation that $a_n = 3a_{n-3}$ holds for $5\leq n \leq 100$, we can define sequence

$$a_{3n+k}=k\cdot 3^n,\ k = 2,3,4,\, n\in\mathbb N.$$

We want to prove that $(a_n)$ satisfies the recurrence. We have $a_2 =2,\, a_3=3,\, a_4 = 4$, so that's ok. It remains to see that

$$3a_{3n+k-3} \geq a_i a_{3n+k-i},\ i = 2,\ldots,3n+k-2$$

and if $i = 3m+j$, we can write the above as

$$
3a_{3(n-1)+k} \geq a_{3m+j} a_{3(n-m)+(k-j)}
\iff  3\cdot k\cdot 3^{n-1} \geq j\cdot 3^ma_{3(n-m)+(k-j)}$$

and this is easy to verify to be true using casework for $k, j \in\{2,3,4\}$.

We conclude that $\max_{i=2,\ldots n-2}\{a_ia_{n-i}\} = a_3 a_{n-3} = 3a_{n-3}$, therefore $$a_n = \max_{i=2,\ldots n-2}\{a_ia_{n-i}\},\ n\geq 4,$$ so $(a_n)$ is the solution of the recurrence.

Comment: Thanks! I believe that the solution could be more elegant though. $a_n=\max\limits_{0<d<n}a_d\cdot a_{n-d}$ describes the biggest value of $a_1\cdot a_{n-1}, a_2\cdot a_{n-2}, ..., a_{n-1}\cdot a_1$. There has to be another key point missing.

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic, yes, maximum is defined as the biggest element. The only way I see to get more elegant solution is to prove $a_n = a_3a_{n-3}$ implies $\max\{a_i a_{n-i}\} = a_3 a_{n-3}$ by induction, using initial conditions only in the basis of induction. Feel free to try it, might work.

Comment: But what is the prime factorization of $a_{19702020}$, I'm a little confused atm

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic, you have explicit formula for the whole sequence, what are you confused about?

Comment: Oh, I didn't update the page. Thanks!

Comment: To counter-check, what did you get?

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic, $a_{19702020} = a_{3\cdot 6567339 + 3} = 3\cdot 3^{6567339} = 3^{6567340}$.